# Change resolution of headless Mac mini when connecting over screen sharing

Tags: display, mac-mini, resolution

Any way to choose a lower resolution than 1920 x 1080 when connecting to a headless Mac mini through screen sharing?

The Display tab in System Preferences is not very helpful since the Scaled option below does not show any other resolutions. Have tried [Display Menu](http://displaymenu.milchimgemuesefach.de/index.html) and [Resolutionator](https://manytricks.com/resolutionator/) with no luck. They both just show one resolution.

[image: displays menu]

Comment: Do you specifically want a lower resolution ["HD" 1080p isn't exactly large by modern standards] or do you just want it to take up less desktop space? I've never tried Screen Sharing, I use Apple Remote Desktop, but on that you can just drag the remote window to any size you want.

Comment: I am trying to view 1080p scaled to 1280x800 and the text becomes really illegible. Would like to use 720p instead of 1080p.

Comment: Get one of those pseudo-adapters that make the machine think it has a real monitor.  They are often used in colo's.  $20 or so from Amazon.

Comment: I have the same question, except wanting to increase the resolution.